# How to delete image from directory and database in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, delete-file

i have a problem in my delete function. the status showing the image and data was successfully deleted from directory and database, but when i check in the database, no data and image was deleted from directory and database.
here is my delete link in view

```
<a class="btn btn-orange btn-xs" href="<?=base_url()?>index.php/root/slider/hapus/?id=<?=$row->id?>"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i></a>
```

here is my delete function in controller

```
 public function hapus(){
   $id  = $this->input->post('id'); 
   $path = './asset/slider/uploads/';
   $path1 = './asset/slider/hasil_resize/';
   $arraydelete  = array('id'=>$id);
   $rowdel = $this->Model_slider->get_byimage($arraydelete);
   @unlink($path.$path1.$rowdel->namafile);
   $this->Model_slider->get_delete($arraydelete);
   $this->session->set_flashdata("pesan", "<div class=\"col-md-12\"><div class=\"alert alert-danger\" id=\"alert\">Berhasil hapus data Gambar dan file gambar dari folder !!</div></div>");
   redirect('root/slider');
```

}

and here is my Model

```
var $tabel = 'slider_home';

function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
}


function get_allimage() {
    $this->db->from($this->tabel);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result();

}
function get_byimage($where) {
    $this->db->from($this->tabel);
    $this->db->where($where);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    if ($query->num_rows() == 1) {
        return $query->row();
    }
}
function get_delete($where){
   $this->db->where($where);
   $this->db->delete($this->tabel);
   return TRUE;
}
```

i need solution for this problem, every time i checked it and fix it, the result still same. Please help me

Comment: in @unlink($path.$path1.$rowdel->namafile); it should be either $path or $path1

Comment: show your form , the anchor containing the link looking as normal link , not a post form

Comment: show your controller name pls be precise on details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you debug your app? Does you have id of image in your $id variable? You check POST, but send id of image in url, for this you need GET

Comment: Please visit [answer]

Comment: woow, how can i not be thorough, it's really work thanks, i really did'nt see that thank you for telling me.